# Regex in Python not grabbing all matches yet a third-party regex tester suceeds

Tags: python, regex

I have a string similar to this:

```
### init.sh [bash]
#!/c/Progra~2/Git/bin/sh.exe
git commit -am "[$1] $2"; git push
```

I've been trying to match both the "init.sh" and the "[bash]", and I have a regex string which works fine on [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), yet doesn't work in Python.

The regex string is `^(?<!\\)###\s*(.*?)(?:\[(.+?)\])?\s*$(?m)`, and I am grabbing the matches via

```
for match in _section_marker_re.finditer(code):
    filename, lang = match.groups()
```

Where `_section_marker_re` is `re.compiled(regex)` and `code` is the string I want to regex on.

What could possibly be happening with Python here?

**EDIT**: I'm using Python 2.7.3 and VERBOSE is not on.

**EDIT 2**: The code using this string goes like this:

```
def highlight_multifile(code):
    """Multi-file highlighting."""
    result = []
    last = [0, None, 'text']

    def highlight_section(pos):
        start, filename, lang = last
        section_code = _escaped_marker.sub('', code[start:pos])
        if section_code:
            result.append(u'<div class="section">%s%s</div>' % (
                filename and u'<p class="filename">%s</p>'
                    % escape(filename + ' - ' + lang) or u'',
                highlight(section_code, lang)
            ))

    for match in _section_marker_re.finditer(code):
        start = match.start()
        highlight_section(start)
        filename, lang = match.groups()
        if lang is None:
            lang = get_language_for(filename)
        else:
            lang = lookup_language_alias(lang)
        last = [match.end(), filename, lang]

    highlight_section(len(code))

    return u'<div class="multi">%s</div>' % u'\n'.join(result)
```

I'm using _escaped_marker as `re.compile(r'^\\(?=###)(?m)')`, which marks the start of the next section.

Comment: What is the initial negative lookbehind meant for?

Comment: @guido: I don't know why I've put it there, it seems unneeded. (Removing it changes nothing)

Comment: The `[bash]` is sometimes omitted in your data? Or is it always present?

Comment: your regex looks good (besides the lookbehind). Problem is probably in the code

Comment: @Bakuriu It is sometimes omitted. Though, in all of the tests I've done so far, it is present. The problem is that filename matches (1st cap. group, "init.sh"), yet lang doesn't (2nd cap. group, "[bash]").

Comment: Could you show a sample of the output you are getting and what you would expect instead? Because to me it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Bakuriu This is for a website, so it's running through webpy.
I'm expecting the regex to match both the filename and the language. This is for a pastebin-type service, so I have to pump the language value to my syntax highlighter. An example input for it would be: `### init.sh [bash]
#!/c/Progra~2/Git/bin/sh.exe  
git commit -am "[$1] $2"; git push
### restart.sh [bash]
#!/bin/sh /var/www/pyimg/stop; 
/var/www/pyimg/start`

Comment: ... which a live demo of the result is available [here](http://p.summerglaufc.org/pastebin/vYRRt). (I've made it so it can auto-detect the language at the moment, but that is far from an actual solution)

Answer (score 0):

This regex seem to work properly:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^###\s*([^\[]+?)\s+(?:\[(.*?)\])?\s*', re.MULTILINE)
>>> text = """###init.sh [bash]
... #! c/Progra~2/Git/bin/sh.exe
... git commit -am "[$1] $2"; git push"""
>>> text2 = text.replace('[bash]', '')   #[bash] omitted
>>> regex.match(text).groups()
('init.sh', 'bash')
>>> regex.match(text2).groups()
('init.sh', None)
```

**Edit:** Even your regex gives the same results. Probably you should provide some more input data to understand why it fails.

```
>>> regex2 = re.compile(r'^(?<!\\)###\s*(.*?)(?:\[(.+?)\])?\s*$', re.MULTILINE)
>>> regex2.match(text).groups()
('init.sh ', 'bash')
>>> regex2.match(text2).groups()
('init.sh', None)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this changes anything, but I have to iterate the regex seeing as there is more than one `### text [text]` line, which I am doing with `for match in _section_marker_re.finditer(code):`

Comment: I've added the function using this regex to the OP.